Unknown abbreviation
I am looking at P&IDs from a nuclear plant built in 1978. I have run across the letter "Y" in instrument descriptions i.e.PCT-, LCY-, FCY-, LY-, etc.  What do they represent?

Solenoids, relays: more generally, transducers, interfaces between electric and pneumatic control systems, or even digital microprocessors which transform data.
Piping and Instrumentation diagrams use standard pictographs and standard abbreviations. PC T is Pressure Control,Transmitter. LCY is a Level Control relay/solenoid/. FC is Flow Control,
LY is a .. Level Transducer, but it doesn't say if it is a Transmitter, Controller or ... what.
